# What mistakes am I committing on this text, and how should I improve it?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

It's been a long time since I checked my English, and I feel like I might not be sounding like a native or it's too flat, I'd like to know what is wrong with the following comment (even slight mistakes, or if it doesn't sound like an American native English speaker), and how I can improve it:

> I've been bombarded by a lot of people saying that Angular was lighter than jQuery on some tasks, and I set out for testing Angular's performance and I've been quite unsatisfied with it, but people still hammer on that, that's why I asked for facts, and I know that here on SO, I would find solid and backed up information, not just opinions

Comment: Even my question is open to judgements :)

Comment: I would recommend [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/) to get folks to look over your writing. This sort of review is really outside the scope of ELL.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't know if there are grammar errors on it as well

Comment: Looks like a run-on sentence... I'd try to split it up.

Comment: @legowave440 yeah, I see that now, it's like a blob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the sentence up into several sentences with a few additional transitions and punctual elements.  This would give it a more natural sound:

> I've been bombarded by a lot of people saying that Angular was lighter than jQuery on some tasks.  **As a result**, I set out for testing Angular's performance and have been quite unsatisfied with it.  **Nevertheless**, people still hammer on that; that's why I asked for facts.  I know that here on SO, I would find solid and backed up information--not just opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can honestly say I have no clue what this sentence is saying, but that's just because I'm extremely ignorant on the subject! :p

Grammar-wise, I would change "set out for testing" to either "set out to test" or just "tested" if that would still make sense with your meaning.

This may be nitpicking, but I would put a period after performance (and of course, drop the "and").